# Azure docker compose

Tags: azure, docker

I need some help.

I tried to start multiple docker containers with different prots by docker-compose on Azure AppService.
Why is app service doesn't set ports from docker-compose settings and set random ports?
Why ports which set app service also not working ?
I can't open this  https://myapp:5110, https://myapp:5120 and also can't open https://myapp:2315

[That's my docker-compose settings file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkvyZ.png)
[That's azure app service log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRqEC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Service listens only on ports 80 and 8080.  If you need to expose multiple containers, you need to add and configure a reverse proxy to your Docker Compose file, make it listen on port 80 and route the traffic to your containers.